# Restoring NuGet packages to the cache

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have a `.net-core` application that works on my machine but when I deploy it on another one, it complains about missing packages and points me to the `TheApp.deps.json`.

---

My theory is that on my machine the app looks for packages in some NuGet cache where they were probably installed by the IDE during development because the app's output-dir contains only a couple of *internal* `dll`s so the other `nuget.org` dependecies are definitely *missing*.

I'm building the app with

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and then *`xcopy`* it to the other machine.

---

#### Question

Is there a way to *restore* or *install* the missing packages to the *cache* on the target machine based on the `*.deps.json` file?

Comment: Are the packages published to an internal/external feed ( NuGet or VSTS, etc;)?

Comment: @TonyAbrams yes, in this case all packages come from `nuget.org`

Comment: How are you deploying the app?

Comment: @TonyAbrams I'm compiling it as `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` and then just `xcopy` it to another PC.

Comment: Due to the xcopy part, I think that your (only) option is to manually install the package on the new machine via NuGet.exe.

Comment: I would use the `dotnet publish` command (if you're working in the CLI), as it collects all of your application's dependencies. Then I'd deploy the publish directory.

Comment: @JamieTaylor you should make this an answer, it's correct. .NET Core projects only write the project output to the bin directory. Publish is needed (can be done from VS as well, right click the project in solution explorer) to get all the dependencies in the folder as well. Then, the publish folder can be copied to other machines.

Comment: @zivkan will do. I'll also expand on my point slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet build` (and the F5/Build function in Visual Studio) simply build the code that you have provided via your source files (i.e cs, fs, vb, etc.).

Whereas `dotnet publish` (and the Build > Publish function in Visual Studio) does a full package restore, builds your source code, and resolves any external dependencies before moving the output to a specific directory ready for publishing to another machine.

The description on the [`dotnet publish` command documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21) states:

> `dotnet publish` compiles the application, reads through its dependencies specified in the project file, and publishes the resulting set of files to a directory. The output includes the following assets:
>
> - Intermediate Language (IL) code in an assembly with a dll extension.
> - *.deps.json* file that includes all of the dependencies of the project.
> - *.runtime.config.json* file that specifies the shared runtime that the application expects, as well as other configuration options for the runtime (for example, garbage collection type).
> - The application's dependencies, which are copied from the NuGet cache into the output folder.

`dotnet build` is only really useful for building on your development machine, and when used in conjunction with `dotnet run` against a project file.

Comment: This actually makes sense now because this way builds are (probably) faster as fewer files are copied to the output directory.

Comment: Yup. Plus, the [NuGet global cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) is used to look for packages while developing locally - which is why you only have to do a `dotnet restore` once (until you add a reference to another NuGet package)